# Retrieve Current User's Data (user_id) Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image]

```
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDb = mDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userKey = user.getUid();

        mDb.child(userKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue());

                userID = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I do not know what is wrong with my code, I want to retrieve value of user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mDb = mDatabase.getReference();
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
userKey = user.getUid();

mDb.child("Tunanetra").child(userKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userID = dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + userID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

With this code, you'll be able to print out in the logcat, the `id` of the users that is authenticated and exists under `Tunanetra` node. If the user exists under the `Orangtua` node, then just change `Tunanetra` with `Orangtua`.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
mDb = mDatabase.getReference();
```

you should be using

```
mDb = mDatabase.getReference("Tunanetra");
```

because that's where the user you're looking for is nested at.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. 
If you want to retrieve user data. Then you have to first select the child node in which you want to look for the user.

You have to Nodes Tunanetra and Orangtua

Else you can try this order by approach.

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference mDb = mDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userKey = user.getUid();

        //First Approach
        mDb.child("Tunanetra").child(userKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String userID = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //Second Approach
        mDb.child("Tunanetra").orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail()).limitToFirst(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                    for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String userID = String.valueOf(data.child("user_id").getValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```