# Firebase Android: Getting data stored in user Id then to the random Push().getKey() value

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

My Previous question was closed and was linked to some other same questions but non of them cover my case and I still require some help. The post they were linked to were:

[Android: Retrieve data of a specific user from a Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999599/android-retrieve-data-of-a-specific-user-from-a-firebase-database)

[Retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714936/retrieving-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-in-android)

[Retrieve Current User's Data (user_id) Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409468/retrieve-current-users-data-user-id-firebase)

However, I am still struggling and hope someone can help me.

[image]

As you can see that it has an User ID first then has the random key then the two information i want to get. My application keeps crashing when i try to get the information

My code in what i am currently doing:
`onCreate`

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

After that:

```
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String userID = user.getUid();
    databaseReference.child(userID).child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Author author = data.getValue(Author.class);
                authorList.add(author);
            }
            SavedQuotes savedQuotes = new SavedQuotes(ShowQuotes.this, authorList);
            list.setAdapter(savedQuotes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

The savedQuotes class has this information:

```
public SavedQuotes(Activity activity, List<Author> authorQuotes){
    super(activity, R.layout.activity_saved_quotes, authorQuotes);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.authors = authorQuotes;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_saved_quotes, null, true);

    name = listView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    quotes = listView.findViewById(R.id.quote);

    Author author = authors.get(position);
    name.setText(author.getName());
    quotes.setText(author.getQuote());

    return listView;
}
```

I hope you can help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `databaseReference.push().getKey()` here. Check below:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

databaseReference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Author author = data.getValue(Author.class);
            authorList.add(author);
        }

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was helpful, I thought i had to get each layer